# Using Bash Less and Grep together

Tags: bash, grep, tail, less-unix, logfile-analysis

I have been trying to follow and filter an log file using

```
less +F +G /var/log/messages |  grep -v -f ignoredwords.txt | grep -f words.txt
```

but it seems the file is not continoulsy read and the operation stops once the whole file is read

i have tried using same with tail -f but that seems to be skipping alot of lines 
any suggestion to improve

Comment: depending on your version, you could use `grep --line-buffered` or install and use `stdbuf -o0 grep ...`

Comment: `less` is wrong here, you want simply `tail -0f` (perhaps with some additional options).

Comment: this doesnot seem to be a problem which duplicate grep , even using single grep and less terminates once the whole file is read (does not keep following the file)

Comment: i have been using tail , but that seems to be missing few lines or may be i am performing too much for grep , i have like 30 words in match and about 40 in ignore words list...any suggestions

Comment: Yes, exactly. The pipe causes buffering. This is a common FAQ. Maybe replace the two `grep`s with a single Awk script, somewhat also depending on the sizes of the word lists.

Comment: struggling with awk , as it couldnt use the words from file to search for..

Comment: awk certainly can use words from a file. It's a programming language, you can write any program in it you want, including a program that reads the first file it's given into a map and checks lines in the second file against that map.